# Webdriver sampler WebDriverWait is taking implicit time rather than explicit time

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter

In Jmeter webdriver when I try to wait for an element using explicit time, the wait statement is taking the browser implicit time. In the below code I have set my browser wait time for 60 secs but in the wait function I am passing only 20 secs before the condition is failed. But the wait statement took full 60 secs before it fails

```
var selenium = org.openqa.selenium
var time = JavaImporter(java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)
WDS.browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, time.TimeUnit.SECONDS)
var support_ui=JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui) 
var EC = org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.log.info("Load the application");
WDS.sampleResult.subSampleStart('Load the application')
WDS.browser.get('https://ea-webapp-int.xxx.com/getting-started')
WDS.log.info("Pass 1")
try {
    var Disc_Agree_button = waitByElement(selenium.By.xpath("//button/span[text()='Agree & Login']"), EC.presenceOfElementLocated, 20)
    WDS.log.info("Pass 2")
    if (undefined !== Disc_Agree_button && Disc_Agree_button.length) {
        WDS.log.info('Disclaimer screen displayed and clicking on Agree button')
        Disc_Agree_button.click()
    }else{
        WDS.log.info('Disclaimer screen not displayed')
    }
} catch (error) {
        WDS.log.info(error)
      WDS.log.info('Disclaimer screen not displayed')
}
 WDS.sampleResult.subSampleEnd(true)
 WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()

function waitByElement(elementBy, conditionToExpect, timer){
    var support_ui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait)
    WDS.log.info(conditionToExpect)
    try{
        var wait = new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser,timer)
        element = wait.until(conditionToExpect(elementBy));
        return element;
    }catch (error){
        WDS.log.info(error)
    }
}
```

If you check the timestamp in the below console output we can notice that the time between first Pass and second pass took 60 secs.

```
2022-03-29 17:04:41,737 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Load the application 
2022-03-29 **17:04:45,689 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler:Pass 1** 
2022-03-29 17:05:45,875 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath:
//button/span[text()='Agree & Login'] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500
milliseconds interval) 
2022-03-29 **17:05:45,876 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Pass 2** 
2022-03-29 17:05:45,877 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Disclaimer screen not displayed
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to read [Selenium documentation on waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#implicit-wait)?

> Implicit waiting for elements to appear is disabled by default and will need to be manually enabled on a per-session basis. Mixing explicit waits and implicit waits will cause unintended consequences, **namely waits sleeping for the maximum time even if the element is available or condition is true**.

> Warning: Do not mix implicit and explicit waits. Doing so can cause unpredictable wait times. For example, setting an implicit wait of 10 seconds and an explicit wait of 15 seconds could cause a timeout to occur after 20 seconds.

Also you're silently ignoring all the exceptions in the [catch block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch), maybe it worth throwing the error back after you handled it instead of suppressing.

You may find [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered) article useful as well.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T, I am using the Explicit wait per need basis and now its running as expected. one more thing you mentioned that I am suppressing the error, but I am writing the error to my console with this statement `WDS.log.info(error)`. Is there something else I am missing here. Even in your article I see you are logging it as Error instead of Info.